# cakephp3 isUnique rule need to use entered value in error message

Tags: cakephp-3.0, validationrules

I need to show the validation message along with the entered value in isUnique rule.

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add(
            $rules->isUnique(
                ['user_name'],
                'This User Name is already in use'
            )
        );
        return $rules;
    }
```

Above code will display error message 'This User Name is already in use' when the user name is a duplicate one. But I want the message as "User name -entered name- is already in use"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a cakephp way of doing this.

but you could try:

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add(
        $rules->isUnique(
            ['user_name'],
            'This User Name ' . $_POST['user_name'] . ' is already in use'  
        )
    );
    return $rules;
}
```

it works for me when I use it like:

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator->add['user_name', 'unique' [
       'rule'=> 'validateUnique',
       'provider' => 'table',
       'message' => 'Username ' $_POST['user_name'] . ' is already in use'
    ]);
    return $validator;
```

}

Comment: Doesn't direct use of user input like this open you up to things like cross-site scripting attacks?

Comment: I don't know Greg if that is possible. I just tested it to see if it would work, I don't use it like this myself (the original input is usually on screen anyway). Might be a good idea to sanatize the input just to be sure if you wanted to use it like this